# jsbeautify jquery chaining

Tags: jquery, code-formatting

I'm using jsbeautifier via the command line (http://jsbeautifier.org/) and it works brilliantly other than it cats my longer jquery chained statements:

```
$('#foo').closest('div')
         .closest('input')
         .val();
```

to:

```
$('#foo').closest('div').closest('input').val();
```

Obviously, thats a bit simple, but sometimes the chaining gets a little longer or its an if-statement like this:

```
if ((foo === bar) && 
    c > 5 && 
    d != 2)
```

where it ends up as:

```
if ((foo === bar) && c > 5 && d != 2)
```

Has anyone experienced this and modified the beautifier or know of a workaround or alternate parser (I use VIM so I'd prefer not to use an IDE solution like aptana unless it could be called via command-line)?  Or do I need to just adjust my code to avoid long if-conditions (and whats the best way to abstract that into something more readable if thats the case)?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been meaning to look into this myself +1

Answer (score 0):

Long if-conditions are quite difficult to read back and debug. You could try the following:

```
var matchesBar = (foo === bar),
    greaterThenFive = (c > 5),
    notTwo = (d != 2);

if (matchesBar && greaterThenFive && notTwo) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

If you give the variables meaningful names you separate out the working out of the truthy parts and their comparison, and the `if` statement is slightly easier to read.

It doesn't directly answer your question re: jsbeautifier but it might help with legibility if there's no other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-B` or `--break-chained-methods` in your command line to preserve those line breaks.

For `if` and other statements, use `-w` or `--wrap-line-length` to break them once the limit is reached.

From the [source](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)

`-B, --break-chained-methods    Break chained method calls across subsequent lines
-w, --wrap-line-length         Maximum characters per line (0 disables) [250]`

Other than that, depending on your code, it is always preferential to not have long `if` or any statement for that matter. I personally try to stick within the 80-char limit but occasionally have to accept longer statements (especially when dealing with legacy projects).